# Where does the phpunit.xml point to?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

i'm desperately trying to make work PHPUnit with Zend Framework 1.11. In my phpunit.xml i need to be sure about the location it points to.

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php" colors="false">
    <testsuite name="ApplicationTestSuite">
        <directory>./application</directory>
        <directory>./library/</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../application</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../library/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".phtml">../applications/views</directory>
                <file>../applications/Bootstrap.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/coverage" charset="UTF-8"
             yui="true" highlight="false" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

All this:

```
./Application
 ./library
 ../application/Bootstrap.php
```

point to the **tests directory** and not the application directory , right ?

Because i always have a fatal error : require_once : failed opening required controllerTestCase.php...

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you could have different `Bootstrap.php` files - one for running the app normally and one for testing it. 
Create a `tests` directory **at the level of your** `Application` directory. Your `phpunit.xml` will reside in that new directory. This is what the insides of the `tests` dir could look like:

```
./Application/
./Application/Bootstrap.php
./Application/ExampleControllerTestCase.php
./log/
./phpunit.xml
```

And your phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="./Application/Bootstrap.php" colors="true">
    <testsuite name="ExampleTests">
        <directory>./Application</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../Application/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".phtml">../Application/</directory>
                <file>../Application/Bootstrap.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="log/" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" hightlight="true" lowupperbound="50" highlowerbound="80">
        <log type="testdox" target="log/">
    </log></log></logging>
</phpunit>
```

Notice that:

1. The `<phpunit  bootstrap="./application/Bootstrap.php" colors="true">` points to the `Bootstrap.php` file in the `tests/Application/` directorry.
2. The "whitelisted" application directory is the one at the upper level - i.e. at the same position as the `tests` directory.
3. `.phtml` files and the "runtime" `Bootstrap.php` are excluded.

You should also have a testing database since some tests requeire deleting/inserting/updating data. In your case the "testsuite" tag does point to the `tests` direcotry provided that the `phpunit.xml` is in that directory.